# (UK) EU Withdrawl Act & The EU

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, parliament

I was reading somewhere that if the Withdrawal Act gets amended too much it's got to be referred back to the EU. Is there an arbitrary limit to the number of amendments that can be made before it has to be referred back to the EU.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's about the content of the amendments, not the quantity of them.

If there is any amendment which is explicitly contradictory to the content of the Withdrawal Agreement Treaty, then the EU will have to agree with it, otherwise ratification of the said treaty cannot proceed.